# Conditional merging of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

My head is hurting after read post after post on this, and i cannot get the gist of how to solve this.

I have 2 pandas dataframes containing sports matches (simplified here):

```
A: Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam
B: Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, HomeScore, AwayScore
```

`A` and `B` must merge into `A`.

`A`contains more matches than `B`, and thus, `A`is larger than `B`The size of `A`must be preserved (consider `A`our "master").

`B`must fill in the HomeScore and AwayScore for each row where Date, HomeTeam and AwayTeam matches.

How can i merge these two properly?

I have considered using `iterrows()` or panda conditions `pd[(a == b)]`, but I can not see how to solve it.

Comment: can you share your create statement for pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `merge()` using the option `how = 'left'` to specify that you want to do a left join keeping the rows of A.

Here is what it could look like :

```
A = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2019-06-12', '2019-08-06', '2019-08-06'],
                  'HomeTeam' : ['Team A', 'Team B', 'Team C'],
                  'AwayTeam' : ['Team D', 'Team E', 'Team F']})
B = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2019-06-12', '2019-08-06'],
                  'HomeTeam' : ['Team A', 'Team B'],
                  'AwayTeam' : ['Team D', 'Team E'],
                  'HomeScore' : [54, 64], 'AwayScore' : [12, 16]})

A.merge(B, on = ['Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam'], how = 'left')
```

---

Output :

```
         Date HomeTeam AwayTeam  HomeScore  AwayScore
0  2019-06-12   Team A   Team D       54.0       12.0
1  2019-08-06   Team B   Team E       64.0       16.0
2  2019-08-06   Team C   Team F        NaN        NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.join`

```py
idxs = ['Date', 'HomeTeam', 'AwayTeam']
joined = A.set_index(idxs).join(B.set_index(idxs), how='left').reset_index()
```

This will produce a dataframe with as many rows as in `A` but with extra columns which will get the value from `B` or be `NaN` if the corresponding combination of values of `idx` doesn't appear there. You are performing a left join, using SQL terms.

Comment: It seems to be working. Is there a way to specify that only the "HomeScore" and "AwayScore" should be joined? (The dataset contains more columns)

Comment: Use `B[['HomeScore', 'AwayScore']]` instead of plain `B`

Comment: When i do, i get this: ```AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'```

Comment: I had a typo in the comment, now it's fixed. Are you sure you are indexing `B` with a list of column names? This shouldn't output a `pd.Series` but a new `pd.DataFrame` instead. Anyway, if the problem persists, consider posting a new question where you can fully explain the details

Comment: I solved it by doing: ```b_df = b_df[["Date", "HomeTeam", "AwayTeam", "HomeScore", "AwayScore"]]```